# Can't find a way to change reactjs element position on runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote some react.component and i define the position as fixed.
i need to move this element position on runtime and

```
 render(){
    var t = <div className="myElement" />;
    t.top = '${500}px';
    t.left = '${900}px';

     return t;     // the element position need to be now 500, 900 
 }
```

Comment: You want to pass those css properties to the `div` on `render()`?

Comment: yes ... i must move the element position to specific location on my screen

Comment: I think you confusing elements written in `jsx` with DOM elements. These are two totally different things. They do not have properties such as `top` or `left`. To apply styles to a component you can use the `style` prop as explained in @Chris answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to pass some inline css rules:

```
render(){
  const s = {top: '500px', left: '900px'};
  return (
    <div className="myElement" style={s} />
  );
}
```

or, the more compact version:

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="myElement" style={{top: '500px', left: '900px'}} />
  );
}
```

React will automatically `px` if a unit is missing. So you can also do: `{top: 500, left: 900}`

---

From the [**docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string. This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes.

Comment: is the 500 and the 900 is dynamic - and i get them on some event ( mouse ) listerner - how do i update it to get them in the render ?

Comment: save them to the state with `setState`. For example `this.setState({top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX});` (for mouse position). Then in your `div` use: `style={{top: this.state.top, left: this.state.left}}`

Answer (score 1):

For this you can try the following method,

```
render(){
let newStyle={
  top:500,
  left:900,
  position:"fixed",
}

return <div style={newStyle} />
}
```

Here you can assign any value at runtime for the location of the element during runtime by setting the value at the place of 500 and 900. Thus making the size dynamic.